# Grep not returning expected value Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I'm trying to grep a value in Perl:

```
@array = ['hello', 'world'];

if (grep(/hello/i, @array) {
   # do something
}
```

For some reason my code isn't picking this up. Perhaps there's another way I can do this.

the Array itself is inside a hash:

```
hash => {
    array => ['hello', 'world'],
    value => 'feature',
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage is indeed

```
if (grep(/hello/i, @array)) { ... }
```

But according to the comments, you don't have a named array. You have a reference to an array. As such, you replace `@array` with an array dereference.

```
if (grep(/hello/i, @$array_ref)) { ... }
```

That's short for

```
if (grep(/hello/i, @{ $array_ref })) { ... }
```

Since your reference comes from a hash, you could also do

```
if (grep(/hello/i, @{ $hash{$key} })) { ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

You're building your array wrong.  This line creates a one-element array, and that element is an array reference.

```
@array = ['hello', 'world'];
```

When you grep over that one-element array, that one array reference doesn't match `/hello/i`.

What you want is:

```
@array = ('hello', 'world');
```

Comment: Hi, The problem with this is the array is inside a hash which is only scalar context    hash => ['hello', 'world']

Comment: Then you can dereference it with `@`.  You could do `@array = @{$hash{key}};`.  See `perldoc perlreftut` for a tutorial on how to use references.

Answer (score 3):

After

```
@array = ['hello', 'world'];
```

you have:

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -e '@array = ['hello', 'world']; print Dumper \@array'
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'hello',
            'world'
          ]
        ];
```

That is `@array` contains a reference to an anonymous array containing the strings `'hello'` and `'world'`.

Then, in grep, you evaluate this reference as a string. Therefore, your `grep` does a single comparison along the lines of

```
'ARRAY(0x7fa0e38032b8)' =~ /hello/i;
```

Clearly, that is not going to match.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (array => ['hello', 'world']);

if (grep /hello/i, @{ $hash{array} }) {
   print "\@array contains 'hello'\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Array itself is inside a hash:

```
hash => {
    array => ['hello', 'world'],
    value => 'feature',
}
```

Use `Data::Dumper` to see how exactly you've defined your structure:

```
use Data::Dumper;
use feature qw(say);   # Highly recommend "say" when using Data::Dumper!


my %hash = (
    array => ['hello', 'world'],
    value => 'feature',
);

...
say Dumper \%hash;
```

And see what prints out. (Note the backslash in front, so you're passing in a single reference_ and not a *list of values*).

What you'll see is something like this:

$var = {
      'array' => [ 
             'hello',
             'world',
           ]
    }

That `array` isn't just an array, it's a reference to an array. You need to *dereference* it to get it to work:

```
if ( grep {/hello/i } @{ $hash->{array} } )
```

Or...

```
my @array = @{ $hash->{array} );
if ( grep { /hello/i } @array;
```